# Objective bound when time limit is reached (GUROBI)

Tags: java, gurobi

I am currently working on modelling a certain MIP in gurobi (working in java).
This problem requires a lot of computational time and I don't want to waste more than 100s on each problem. However, when this time limit is reached, I want gurobi to print the best feasable solution it has found within these 100s. I tried using the attribute ObjBound, but this always gives me a lower objective than when I let gurobi find the optimale solution (my problem is a minimization problem). So I'm guessing here that this ObjBound gives a lower bound, while I'm trying to find an upper bound. 
Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply looking to get any feasible solution (not the optimal, just feasbile), set the MIPFocus parameter to 1. This tells gurobi to concentrate on finding a feasible solution rather than an optimal solution.

```
model.setParam('MIPFocus', 1)
model.optimize()
```